# finding smallest value of subset of items from a bigger set

Tags: algorithm, minimum

I have a problem in hand. Just trying to figure out if there is better solution.

So lets say I have some key-value pairs:

```
[
 1234 : 43,
 2134 : 12,
 6543 : 89,
 213 : 45
]
```

Now I want to query them in random subsets and want the minimum associated value.

Eg: Input: **{1234, 2134, 213}** -> 12

 **{6543, 213}** -> 45 ...

One solution I have, is to store the initial data in a map and iterate over the given input and get the minimum.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't think that there is a better way. It is O(n), where n is the number of entries in the set. You will have to look at each number in the set at least once (unless you hit the global minimum earlier, then you could escape).

Answer (score 0):

Storing your subsets in a map forces you to look up every value to find the minimum.

You could store your subsets in an array of keys, sorted by value, and access the minimum of each subset in constant time.

If you sort your data first, and depending how you decide to build your subsets, you could incur a `n.log(n)` initial cost, plus the cost of building the subsets, taking care of maintaining the elements ordered.

Comment: As I understand it the subsets are unknown in advance. So I don't see how this would work.

Comment: It will depend on how the subsets are determined; if it is possible to maintain the order when the subsets are drawn, then the lookup of the minimum value is constant time.

Comment: @maraca you are right. The subsets are random and in no order. Also the initial set is pretty huge. So I do not think having all possible combinations pre-compiled subsets is a possibility.

Comment: @bazinga. I did not suggest that the subsets are precomputed. The algorithm proposes to sort the population, then attempt to keep the subsets in order, during sampling. If the way the subsets are drawn allows it, it is a better solution than to store the initial data in a map and iterate over it.